# How the swing's BoxModel works?

Tags: java, swing, components, positioning, css

Let's say I would like to create a simple calculator. It consists of 3 fields. Text field to show result, field with checkboxes to select system and field with numbers.

What kind of component should I use for each element ?
How can I position elements in my window ?
How can I position elements inside component (ie checkboxes) ?

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/7691/lab8c.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

- `JTextField` for the number-window
- `JRadioButton` for the radio buttons, and
- `JButton` for the buttons.

The layout of the components should be deferred to a so called layout-manager. (Have a look at [Using Layout Managers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). In this case a `GridLayout` and/or a `GridBagLayout` would do fine.

This code should get you started:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class FrameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame Test");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        panel.add(new JTextField(), gbc);


        JPanel numSysPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        numSysPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Number System"));
        numSysPanel.add(new JRadioButton("oct"));
        numSysPanel.add(new JRadioButton("dec"));
        numSysPanel.add(new JRadioButton("hex"));
        panel.add(numSysPanel, gbc);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 2, 2));
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            buttons.add(new JButton("" + i));
        panel.add(buttons, gbc);

        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off, you start with determining, which [`LayoutManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html) you should use, to arrange your three fields. [`GridBagLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) will definitely do what you want, but is quite hard to program. You could try to get away with the simpler [`BorderLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), which will make your application look odd, while resizing. You can use [`GroupLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html) too. `BoxLayout`, `GridLayout` and `FlowLayout` are not what you want to use. Now you have a lot of options, to lay out you top elements.

Use a [`JTextField`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) for the result. Use [`JCheckBox`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBox.html) for the checkboxes, which you put insider a `JPanel` with an etched border (via `JPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder())`) and a `FlowLayout`. Don't forget to put the checkboxes in a [`CheckboxGroup`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxGroup.html). Last but not least use a `JPanel` to group the `JButton`s for the, uhh, buttons. Use a [`GridLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) (5 rows, 4 columns) to arrange these buttons.